# Is there a reason behind creating a Variable for the length of a String instead of using length() Java

Tags: java, string, variables, string-length

I've been practicing Java on CodeBat. When I see other people solutions they create a variable for the length of a string. I was just wondering if there any advantages to creating the variable.

For example I'd write:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
     if (str.charAt(i) == '*'  && str.charAt(i - 1) != str.charAt(i + 1)) {
         return false;
     }
 }
```

Others would write:

```
 int len = str.length();
 for (int i = 1; i < len - 1; i++) {
     if (str.charAt(i) == '*'  && str.charAt(i - 1) != str.charAt(i + 1)) {
         return false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: In some cases, you might need to use the `len` again later, making a separate variable advantageous. Otherwise, the only difference is readability preference.

Comment: Referencing an int is faster than calling a method every single time. Since the length can't change because strings are immutable this is a safe operation.

Comment: It may be intended as a manual optimization, lifting a method invocation out of the loop.  Generally, however, you can rely on the JIT to do that for you dynamically if it's going to be any significant help.

Comment: Thanks you all for the insight.

Answer (score 3):

There's absolutely no difference other than personal preferences:

1. `String`s are immutable in Java, so the length can never change.
2. JIT compiler is smart enough to optimise `length()` call into a simple variable reading, so there will be no performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are appropriate, though the second would be preferable in cases where the length needs to be used again.

Comment: Really not sure about that. See my answer for details but even if it may remove a function call, this optimisation will probably be achieved by the JIT anyway. So I agree that both are appropriate but the second one may is not preferable

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. The length of a java string is O(1) because java's string class stores the length as a field. So in the end it is nothing more than reading a variable. Thus, there will be no performance issue if you use `.length()`

The code for `.length()`, from JDK 1.6 is:

```
public int length() {
    return count;
}
```

Even if it is true that removing the call to the method may be seen as an optimisation, the JIT will probably do it dynamically anyway.

Perhaps in the solutions you have seen, people are writing code that way because they are use to coding in c.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer depends on how many times you might call the `String.length()` function & for readability purposes. 
If you are planning on using the value only once, there should be no need to create a variable to store the value. Otherwise if you will need to use the value more than once, it is more efficient to have a local variable instead of calling `String.length()` every time.

Ultimately, this goes back to personal preference more than anything else.